# Putting css style sheet right under src directory for a javafx project, however it cannot be found

Tags: java, javafx

I placed my css style sheet directly under the src directory, and then I try to add it to my javafx scene with the following piece of code:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```

and then I get the following error:

```
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "style.css" not found.
```

I am using the eclipse IDE and initally I just had the css style sheet in the directory one level behind the src directory and I directly typed out the file path when trying to add the style sheet to my scene, but when using that method I received a null pointer exception. I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't load css file in javafx 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947109/cant-load-css-file-in-javafx-8)

Comment: please read the api doc (of scene.getStyleSheets()) to understand where the sheets are looked up (though it has a rather winded way of stating that it's an absolute path _[path] is treated as a path relative to the root of the application's classpath_ ;)

Comment: Yes, I just realized that the style.css folder has to be in the same directory as the .class files. Thanks :D