# JAVAFX: cannot find the relative path to a file

Tags: java, file, javafx, path

I need to add the file style.css as stylesheet to a scene.
I am trying to do this inside the class ScreenController which is in the package justAnotherChessGame.model.
The file is in the same directory but in a different package.
How can I find the relative path?
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zamci.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your scene is `sc` and pane is `p` in `ScreenController`,

```
Scene sc = new Scene(p, 400, 300);
sc.getStylesheets().add("/justAnotherChessGame/view/style.css");
primaryStage.setScene(sc);
```

You need to study about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946372/adding-css-file-to-stylesheets-in-javafx) case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to access files bundled in an application:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(MainView.class.getResource("style.css").toString());
```

You will need to import MainView so the compiler recognizes its name.