# how to set default color of hyperlink in javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, hyperlink

How do I set hyperlink color to black, which is by default blue?

```java
source=new Hyperlink("source"); source.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20));
source.setLayoutX(920); source.setLayoutY(900);  
source.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Github"));
layout.getChildren().add(source); // here layout is Pane layout
```

I want to set the color of source hyperlink to black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it in CSS:

```css
.hyperlink {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Comment: do I have to create different css file for that?

Comment: @panic you just need to add this to the application’s css file.

Comment: There is no css file in my project directory. Is it supposed to be on project directory?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946372/adding-css-file-to-stylesheets-in-javafx)